Move data from Power BI to SharePoint List
I would like to move the data from my Power BI dashboard table to SharePoint List without duplicates using Power Automate flow. I am using the run query against a dataset and parse JSON function in power automate. I have already created the file. However, it is showing duplicates items whenever I upload the latest updated file. Any solution to this?
